# Performance impact of using Task.WhenAny() in an ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, garbage-collection, async-await

Is the use of Task.WhenAny() in an ASP.Net application considered bad practice? If I have a method that takes a stockQuote and calls several services for a price but I return the first result I get back, what are the implications if this is done often in an application?

```
public async Task<decimal> GetStockQuote(string stockSymbol)
{
    var task1 = PriceFromServiceOne(stockSymbol);    // Returns first
    var task2 = PriceFromServiceTwo(stockSymbol);    // Contains exception
    var task3 = PriceFromServiceThree(stockSymbol);  // Take 5 mins to return

    // What happens to the other two tasks?
    var priceTask = await Task.WhenAny(task1, task2, task3); 
    decimal price = await priceTask;
    return price;
}
```

Are there ramifications on the web application due to the two non-awaited tasks when

1. The web request that called this method completes
2. Garbage collection is called in the web application

Is there a better way to handle this scenario and are there differences when the unobserved task is faulted compared to being long running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cancel the remaining tasks as they will run to completion but will be ignored (the same for the exceptions).
Consider cancelling remaining task using `CancellationToken` after the first one returns.